# Android Studio - Program type already present: org.bouncycastle.LICENSE

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this error when I try to build project, someone can help me?
If I sync project and I clean it everything works.

here full logs:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
...
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list
...
Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: org.bouncycastle.LICENSE
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:131)
...
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: org.bouncycastle.LICENSE
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1990)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:124)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:123)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
...
```

Comment: Add this to your module build.gradle file   `configurations.all {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'}`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following gradle snippet to exclude LICENCE files and other conflicting resources between libs

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cristian, thank you for replying...I already exclude LICENCE but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.1.0'` is working for me.